# What is max traffic limit on Ipage shared hosting plan?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, optimization, shared-hosting

I am using shared hosting plan of Ipage for a WordPress site and I recently had a trouble with the db queries. Can  anyone here tell me the relation between traffic(users) and db queries?
For my website max query limit is 10, can I hold up to `2k` traffic per day with this limit?

Comment: "my website max query limit is 10"  10 queries ever?  10 concurrent?  10 per second?  10 per day?  In general this question can't be answered without knowing how many queries the average request does, which depends on the wordpress version, which plugins you're using, how often the backend is used, etc.

Comment: I am not an web developer that's why i talk somewhat wrong. Support told me that I exceeded the db connection limit that was 10 just 10. Thats why they suspended the site.

Comment: @Ossir please don't backtick technology names. Inline code markup is for inline code and very little else - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text/254995#254995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from my host. 25 'processes' is their limit. With lots of plugins and sites, I was hitting their limit. (about 400 plugins over 30 low traffic sites). Apparently the dB stays 'open' if you hit the limit and processes do not complete, causing dB corruption.

Move to non-shared hosting is likely the answer.